# kotlin - Pass method reference to function

Tags: reflection, jvm, kotlin, method-reference

Let's say I have the following Java class:

```
public class A {
   public Result method1(Object o) {...}
   public Result method2(Object o) {...}
   ...
   public Result methodN(Object o) {...}
}
```

Then, in my Kotlin code:

```
fun myFunction(...) {
    val a: A = ...
    val parameter = ...
    val result = a.method1(parameter) // what if i want methodX?
    do more things with result
}
```

and I want to be able to choose which methodX will be called inside `myFunction`. in Java, I would pass `A::method7` as an argument and call it. in Kotlin it doesn't compile. How should I solve it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also pass the method reference in Kotlin (without needing the heavy hammer that is reflection):

```
fun myFunction(method: A.(Any) -> Result) {
    val a: A = ...
    val parameter = ...
    val result = a.method(parameter)
    do more things with result
}

myFunction(A::method1)
myFunction {/* do something in the context of A */}
```

This declares `method` as part of `A`, meaning you can call it with normal `object.method()` notation. It Just Works™ with the method reference syntax.

There's also another form that works with the same call syntax, but makes `A` more explicit:

```
fun myFunction(method: (A, Any) -> Result) { ... }

myFunction(A::method1)
myFunction {a, param -> /* do something with the object and parameter */}
```

Comment: But you can also pass `{ Result(...) }` for example, which is a random lambda, not defined in `A`

Comment: @s1m0nw1, Yes, that's what my second call does. The lambda body is evaluated in the context of `A`. For example, if `A` has a public `foo` property, then passing `{foo}` would be acceptable as long as type checking works out. But remember that in the context of `A` includes things outside of `A`. One of the things this enables is contained DSLs. For example, you have an `HtmlDsl` class with a local `p` function. You have an `html` function taking an `HtmlDsl.() -> Unit`. The user can do something like `html { p { ... } }`

Comment: I'm aware of this; just wanted to point out that it might not be what OP asked for, not sure though

Comment: @s1m0nw1, Fair enough. I added an alternative form that removes that association.

Comment: chris, so using :: for method referencing is really using reflection, is that right ?

Comment: @j2emanue, While you can use method references with reflection, you can also use method references in cases like this one without bringing in the bulky reflection runtime library. There's nothing here that couldn't be replaced by a simple lambda: `A::method1` → `{ a: A, param: Any -> a.method1(param) }`. The method reference is essentially syntax sugar for uses that don't need reflection.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do this exactly like you wanted to:

```
fun myFunction(kFunction: KFunction2<A, @ParameterName(name = "any") Any, Result>) {
    val parameter = "string"
    val result: Result = kFunction(A(), parameter)
    //...
}

myFunction(A::method1)
myFunction(A::method2)
```